# Error 52 - bad file number

Tags: vba, outlook, runtime-error

the following VBA code is supposed to open a text file, read the number in it to a text file, add 1 to the number in the text file, then save the new number in the text file.

I am currently getting a Error 52 at the line indicated (`While Not EOF(filenum)`). How do I fix this?

```
Public Sub Items_ItemAdd(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim filenum As Integer
Dim current_number As String
Dim fileName As String
Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Set objNS = GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Items = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
filenum = FreeFile()
fileName = "G:\Infrastructure Services\Engineering Services\Hazard Report Number.txt"
Open fileName For Input As filenum
While Not EOF(filenum) '*error 52 - Bad file number
Line Input #filenum, current_number
Close filenum
Wend


If Item.Class = olMail Then
    If Left$(Item.Subject, 29) = "Hazard Identification Report" Then
        Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem
        Dim NewForward As Outlook.MailItem
        Dim myFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
        Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
        Dim olNS As Outlook.NameSpace

        Set Msg = Item
        Set NewForward = Msg.Forward
        Set olApp = Outlook.Application
        Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

        strSender = ""
strsenderName = Msg.SenderEmailAddress





If strsenderName = "EX" Then
  Set objSender = itm.Sender
  If Not (objSender Is Nothing) Then
    Set objExchUser = Sender.GetExchangeUser()
    If Not (objExchUser Is Nothing) Then
      strSender = objExchUser.PrimarySmtpAddress
    End If
  End If
Else
  strSender = strsenderName
End If



        With NewForward
            .Subject = "Hazard report reciept number: & "
            .To = strSender
            .HTMLBody = "TYhank you for your email"
            .Send
        End With
        End If
    End If
    Close filenum

ExitProc:
    Set NewForward = Nothing
    Set Msg = Nothing
    Set olApp = Nothing
    Set olNS = Nothing


End Sub
```

Comment: Try `Open fileName For Input As #filenum`

Comment: @TimWilliams: I thought about that, but the `#` is optional, so that can't be it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're closing your file within the `While ... Wend` loop. So it reads the first line, closes the file, then checks `EOF(filenum)` but `filenum` is no longer a valid handle for an open file, hence the error.

Just move the `Close` statement out of the loop:

```
While Not EOF(filenum) '*error 52 - Bad file number
    Line Input #filenum, current_number
Wend
Close filenum
```

I'm guessing that properly indenting your code would have helped you spot that mistake!

Comment: Good catch!  Totally missed that.

Comment: Thanks for that! I'm now getting a file already open error at the `Open fileName For Input As filenum` line. Any reason you can see?

Comment: Well, is the file already open? Maybe by another instance of Excel, or a different application?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett No it isn't.

Comment: I suggest posting a new question describing exactly what is going on.